# DRF ImportError on importing serializers circular

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am using **Django 2.2** and have two applications `authentication` and `multi_users`

There is `UserSerializer` in `authentication` application. The `multi_users` model has a field `shared_user` and thus using `UserSerializer` in the `multi_users.serializers` to serialize the `shared_user` field.

Now, there is `AccessLevelPermissionSerializer` class in the `multi_users.serializers` which I need in the `authentication.serializers` to serializer `permissions` of the user.

This is giving error as

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'AccessLevelPermissionSerializer' from 'multi_users.serializers' (/app/multi_users/serializers.py)
```

**authentication.serializers**

```
from authentication.models import Profile, User, Preference

class UserBaseSerializer(UserDetailsSerializer):
    class Meta(UserDetailsSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')


class UserSerializer(UserBaseSerializer):
    from multi_users.serializers import AccessLevelPermissionSerializer

    permissions = AccessLevelPermissionSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta(UserDetailsSerializer.Meta):
        fields = UserBaseSerializer.Meta.fields + (
            'permissions'
        )
```

**multi_users.serializers**

```
from authentication.serializers import UserBaseSerializer

class SharedPermissionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SharedPermission
        fields = [
            'code',
            'name',
        ]


class AccessLevelPermissionBaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    permission = SharedPermissionSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = AccessLevelPermission
        fields = [
            'value',
            'permission'
        ]


# Import this in the `authentication.serializers`
class AccessLevelPermissionSerializer(AccessLevelPermissionBaseSerializer):
    pass


class MultiUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    shared_user = UserBaseSerializer(required=False)         # Use from `authentication.serializers`

    class Meta:
        model = MultiUser
        depth = 1
        fields = [
            'id',
            'shared_user',
            'access_level',
        ]
```

**How to resolve this circular import issue?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi may be this will help , try to remove `from authentication.serializers import UserBaseSerializer` from multi_users.serializers because when you try to access

```
from multi_users.serializers import AccessLevelPermissionSerializer

permissions = AccessLevelPermissionSerializer(required=False)
```

this code from authentication.serializers, you being in authentication.serializers try to access `from multi_users.serializers import AccessLevelPermissionSerializer`
which will redirect your call to multi_users.serializers where you are again importing from authentication.serializers import UserBaseSerializer which making it circular being in that file you again access another file which indirectly calling same file so please try to remove `from authentication.serializers import UserBaseSerializer` from multi_users.serializers

Comment: Removing that is working but I need to use `UserBaseSerializer` in there to serializer `shared_user` attribute. Is there any other way? I removed `AccessLevelPermissionSerializer` from `UserBaseSerializer` and using in a different serializer, still error is there.

Comment: I can see you are using UserBaseSerializer only in one class so what a alternative solution I can find is that instead of importing globally try to import into your MultiUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) class that might work